# "DSR is on; Don't send DTR on" error 

Tags: android, serial-communication

When I connect my laptop to my Android phone, the computer aways shows me this error :

```
1827    Data Router             usb connection is true
1827    Data Router             DSR is on Don't send DTR on
```

My phone is galaxy II with Android 4.03.

According to my search:

```
DSR=Data Set Ready    DCE (Data Carrier Detect) is ready to receive commands or data.
DTR=Data Terminal Ready  Indicates presence of DTE to DCE.
```

Comment: I too wish to know how to fix this.

Comment: I think is debug spam samsung left visible in logcat, you also get a lot of spam about luminosity sensor

Comment: DSR, DCE, and DTR are all signal conditions for the RS-232 communications standard.  They do not really have a place in the USB world though it may be that your phone to laptop communication is going through a USB to Serial Communications port converter in which the USB supports a virtual Serial Communications port device.  For Serial Communications there are two entities, the Data Set and the Data Terminal which are communicating over the physical multi-stranded cable.  DSR and DTR lines were raised or lowered depending on whether the DS or the DT were read to receive bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an application error, this is spam in your log from the system. It's okay to ignore unless you're working on the phone's hardware.

Comment: shouldnt i be concerned regarding unnecessary use of resources?  shouldnt i look to configure what is in conflict to stop attempting whatever it is?  tks